# Searching for an empty value in Discover

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I'm trying to query Kibana for a field containing an empty value, or basically just a transaction with a non-existing field.
The Log i have consists transactions with many different fields, and i'm trying to get only the ones that don't have a certain field.

how can i do that?
thanks.

Comment: How does a record look like in your `Kibana > Discover` ?

Comment: Are you mapping your null values to an specific value?

Answer (score 0):

To query all entries with a non-existing field, you can use:

```
NOT (_exists_:fieldname)
```

Comment: I believe alternatively you may also use: `_missing_:fieldname`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use regex:

```
GET my_target_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {"regexp": {
          "my_target_field": ".+"
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```